# Kann sich ein attributives Partizip auf zwei Substantive beziehen?

Tags: grammaticality, participle

Wenn der Mann am Haus steht, ist es

> der am Haus stehende Mann.

Wenn der Mann und die Frau am Haus stehen, kann man dann auch von

> den am Haus stehenden Mann und Frau

oder

> dem und der am Haus stehenden Mann und Frau

sprechen? Ist der Relativsatz notwendig oder sind die Artikel der Subjekte unwichtig?

Comment: Wo tauchen in deiner Frage Relativsätze auf?

Comment: "*das am Haus stehende Paar, ein Mann und eine Frau ...*"

Comment: Ich schlage vor, du gibst uns einen ganzen Satz als Beispiel, nicht nur eine Nominalphrase. Denn wenn nur eine Nominalphrase vorliegt, ist die Frage nach einem Relativsatz ziemlich unsinnig.

Answer (score 3):

"Den ... Mann und Frau" klingt für mich falsch, weil es nicht zu "Frau" passt.

"Dem und der ... Mann und Frau" klingt für mich falsch, weil Artikel und Nomen nicht zusammenstehen.

Ich würde daher "der am Haus stehende Mann und die am Haus stehende Frau" sagen. Das ist zwaar etwas lang, aber wenn Du die Situation besser einschätzen kannst, kannst Du sicher etwas kürzeres finden, z.B. "das am Haus stehende Paar" oder "die am Haus stehenden Leute".

Comment: Ziel war auch die Verkuerzung des Satzes

Comment: @imgonnamakeanacceventually: Dann schreibe dieses Ziel in deine Frage. (Du kannst sie editieren.)

Answer (score 2):

Da sich die Artikel auf einzelne der im Nachfolgenden auftauchenden Fälle (nicht im grammatikalischen Sinn, Fälle im Sinn einer Entscheidung) beziehen, passt hier *beziehungsweise*:

> dem beziehungsweise der am Haus stehenden Mann und Frau

Beachte, dass es wegen des Dativs (der sich anhand der Artikel erkennen lässt) *stehenden* heißen muss.

Comment: Das würde ich jetzt aber doch definitiv als falsch bezeichnen.

Comment: @userunknown: Warum?

Comment: Weil "der am Haus stehenden Mann" nicht geht. "Dem am Haus stehenden Mann bzw. der Frau" ginge, aber m.E. muss das _dem_ beim Mann stehen. Ich kann sagen: "Ich streichle dem Meerschweinchen bzw. der Katze das Fell". Ich kann aber nicht sagen: "Ich streichle dem bzw. der Meerschweinchen Katze das Fell." Oder: "Ich gehe zum Bäcker und zur Friseuse" aber nicht: "Ich gehe zum bzw zur Bäcker und Friseuese."

Answer (score 1):

In der Frage vermischt du leider drei Fälle (*der* Mann, *den* Mann und *dem* Mann), die man gesondert betrachten sollte, sofern man die Konstruktion mit Partizip beibehalten möchte.

#### Nominativ

Aus „**Der** am Haus stehende Mann schaute zu mir herüber“ wird

> - „**Der** am Haus stehende Mann und **die** am Haus stehende Frau schauten zu mir herüber“
>
> oder, mit nachgestelltem Partizip,
>
> - „**Der** Mann und **die** Frau, am Haus stehend, schauten zu mir herüber.“

#### Akkusativ

Aus „Ich sah **den** am Haus stehenden Mann“ wird

> - „Ich sah **den** am Haus stehenden Mann und **die** am Haus stehende Frau.“

Zwar würde auch der Satz „Ich sah **den** Mann und **die** Frau, am Haus stehend“ funktionieren, aber es gibt sicherlich Leute, die ihn missinterpretieren. (Wer steht am Haus?)

#### Dativ

Aus „Ich gab **dem** am Haus stehenden Mann ein Zeichen“ wird

> - „Ich gab **dem** am Haus stehenden Mann und **der** am Haus stehenden Frau ein Zeichen.“

Auch hier würde ich den Satz „Ich gab **dem** Mann und **der** Frau, am Haus stehend, ein Zeichen“ nicht schreiben.

Comment: Ein zwischen Komma und _am_ eingeschobenes _beide_ erhöht die Verständlichkeit. Man kann auch andersrum nachstellen: _Ich gab den am Haus stehenden, (ein) Mann und (eine) Frau, ein Zeichen._

Answer (score 1):

Man kann erst den allgemeinen Plural bilden, und dann die Details aufdröseln, ohne das *am Haus stehen* zu wiederholen:

> Die am Haus Stehenden, der Mann und die Frau, waren reichlich
>   betrunken.

Die Wiederholung vermeidet auch folgende Form:

> Dem am Haus stehenden Mann und der Frau standen Tränen der Rührung in
>   den Augen.

Hier ist nicht ganz sicher, ob die Frau jetzt auch am Haus stand oder nicht. Wenn es sich nicht aus dem Kontext ergibt, und es so wichtig ist, dass man jeden Zweifel vermeiden will, dann muss man eben länger und umständlicher formulieren.

Man kann auch von

> dem Mann und der Frau, die am Haus stehen,

reden. Formulierung mit zwei Mal *am Haus stehen* wirst Du im Sprachgebrauch selten antreffen; falsch sind sie nicht.

Noch eleganter vermeidet man das Problem, in dem man die zweite Person in Relation zur ersten setzt:

> Ich sah den am Haus stehenden Mann und die Frau daneben.

Nicht sagen kann man

> dem und der am Haus stehenden Mann und Frau
>   weil Artikel und Nomen zusammengehören. Hier werden quasi Klammern geöffnet ohne geschlossen zu werden, während eine äußere Klammer noch nicht geschlossen wurde:

```
(dem und <der [am Haus stehenden] Mann) und Frau>
```